# elasticsearch store time series data when there are many properties fields (about 60000 fields)

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series

store 60000 points value every 500 milliseconds with elasticsearch,there are two ways to design elasticsearch mapping:

1.one pointName/one timestamp in one doc,like this:

```
_id    timestamp      pointName  value 
uuid1  1582130490000  p1         1 
uuid2  1582130490000  p2         2 
....
uuid   1582130490500  p1         x
```

2.one timestamp with 60000 pointName in one doc,like this:

```
_id    timestamp       p1  p2  p3  p4 ... p60000
uuid1  1582130490000   1   2   3   4  ... x
uuid2  1582130490500   1   2   3   4  ... x
```

i have tested write/query performance in two uper ways,no problem with aggregate query performance.but batch write performance is too slow,it takes about 1500 milliseconds to write 10000 points with 3 elasticsearch clusters.

is there a bad write performance over 1000 fields in elasticsearch?
how should i to design elasticsearch mapping to store 60000 points every 500 milliseconds with good write performance?

thanks

Comment: 1) First of all, is your mappings optimised? 
2) you can turn off dupplicate and refresh in order to optimize indexation speed. If you dont query at the same time this could be a solution. If you only make full reindexation, you can use alias to keep production on an index.
3) We need to know how you will use your data. 1000 fields is huge, but according to your context, could be ok. Could you tell us a little more?

Comment: @LeBigCat thank you for your reply!
I'm just testing the write speed of two mapping designs. I'm not sure whether it's better to store in column(one timestamp with 60000 pointName in one doc) or in row(1.one pointName/one timestamp in one doc). Can you give me some suggestions on storing 60000 point mapping design?

Comment: @LeBigCat 
1) option 1,i used default parameter settings mapping 
2) option 2,setting and mapping like this:
"settings": {
"index": {
"mapping": {
"total_fields": {
"limit": "60000"
}
},
"refresh_interval": "30s",
"number_of_shards": "5",
"translog": {
"durability": "async"
}
}
},
"mappings": {
"tsdata": {
"properties": {
"SYSUCDPIOSTATUS36BB#DI": {
"type": "double"
},
"SYS_FCS61A_VL10#AV": {
"type": "double"
}
}
}
3).query the avg value of a point by timestamp range whith interval(500ms/1000ms...)

Comment: if you are looking for agregation, the 60000 point mapping design would be better. Indeed elastic wont be really performant if you store this in a huge array (and use nested field would create hidden documents). 
Your mappings seems correct, if you dont need to query on indexation times, turn off refresh duplicate (there are some articles for indexation performance).